# Google inapp billing not restoring some already purchased item details

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I had implemented In-app billing. I have 11 items in my app to purchase. Purchasing of item is working fine.  Initially all items are in locked state and after purchasing I will unlock it. Purchasing of every item is working fine. When I uninstall my app and reinstall it, on the splash screen I am requesting purchased items list, I am getting all the purchased items details apart from 2 particular items, because of this it is showing unlocked in the app.When I try to purchase it again, I am getting the response as already purchased. I checked my wallet account  , in that it is showing those two items as purchased.

Comment: I've seen the same thing in my app - while restoring the transactions the items were not included, but purchasing them again was not possible either. I believe it was some glitch/bug on Google's side.

Comment: No, unfortunately not. I assumed it's a temporary glitch, and my customer didn't complain - perhaps it was too rare to bother?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. When I added my Inapp products into Google Play ,I gave Purchase Type as Unmanaged for those particular two items. Because of this it was showing as notpurchased. I deleted those two items and added those items as new product and gave Purchase Type as Managed y User Account, Now it is working fine.